# Complex Polygon in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to make click event for each of polygons in a complex polygon in google maps v3 ex:

```
var path1 = [new google.maps.LatLng(31.246599, 29.999199),
             new google.maps.LatLng(29.999199, 31.246599),
             new google.maps.LatLng(30.246599,28.999199)];
var path2 = [new google.maps.LatLng(31, 30),
             new google.maps.LatLng(29.999199, 31.246599),
             new google.maps.LatLng(30.246599,28.999199)];

poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [path1, path2],
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map });


 // i want to make click event for a polygon that represents by path1 
 // and the other that represents by path2
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

then create two polygons poly1 and poly2 and handle click events on them:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly1, 'click', function (e) {
    ....
});
google.maps.event.addListener(poly2, 'click', function (e) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: this make event for all the complex polygon not for each part in it

Comment: @M.SH, what you mean with "part of polygon"? There is nothing like "part of polygon" in google.maps. I said "then create two polygons" - which means simply split the complex polygon to smaller ones, that is the solution.

Comment: @M.SH, I just doubled the source, maybe it is more clear now?